# Extract a pattern from column and make a new one in R data frame

Tags: r, regex

I have the following R DataFrame

```
  x                                                                                          y
1 1               "gene_biotype "lincRNA"; gene_id "ENSG00000224818"; gene_name "RP11-134G8.8"
2 2 "gene_biotype "processed_transcript"; gene_id "ENSG00000261067"; gene_name "RP11-264B17.3"
3 3 "gene_biotype "processed_transcript"; gene_id "ENSG00000261067"; gene_name "RP11-264B17.3"
```

I want to extract the `gene_id` from every row and make new column like below,

```
  x               y
1 1 ENSG00000224818
2 2 ENSG00000261067
3 3 ENSG00000261067
```

I have tried `sapply(strsplit(dat$y, 'gene_id \"'), "[", 2)`, but this only removed the preceding pattern. How should I remove the succeeding pattern and extract the `gene_id`

The dataframe can be reproduced using the following

```
x <- c(1:3)
y <- c('"gene_biotype \"lincRNA\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000224818\"; gene_name \"RP11-134G8.8\"',
       '"gene_biotype \"processed_transcript\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000261067\"; gene_name \"RP11-264B17.3\"',
       '"gene_biotype \"processed_transcript\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000261067\"; gene_name \"RP11-264B17.3\"')
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
dat
```

Comment: Try `dat$x <- str_extract(dat$y, '(?<=gene_id ")[^"]+')`, see https://ideone.com/QIpYuR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the word after `"gene_id"` :

```
dat$y <- sub('.*gene_id\\s"(\\w+)";.*', '\\1', dat$y)
dat

#  x               y
#1 1 ENSG00000224818
#2 2 ENSG00000261067
#3 3 ENSG00000261067
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
library(stringr)
dat$x <- str_extract(dat$y, '(?<=gene_id ")[^"]+')
```

The regex pattern (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/qeKCvs/1)) matches

- `(?<=gene_id ")` - a location immediately preceded with `gene_id "` substring
- `[^"]+` - one or more chars other than `"`.

See an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/QIpYuR):

```
x <- c(1:3)
y <- c('"gene_biotype \"lincRNA\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000224818\"; gene_name \"RP11-134G8.8\"',
       '"gene_biotype \"processed_transcript\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000261067\"; gene_name \"RP11-264B17.3\"',
       '"gene_biotype \"processed_transcript\"; gene_id \"ENSG00000261067\"; gene_name \"RP11-264B17.3\"')
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
library(stringr)
dat$x <- str_extract(dat$y, '(?<=gene_id ")[^"]+')
dat
```

Output:

```
                x
1 ENSG00000224818
2 ENSG00000261067
3 ENSG00000261067
                                                                                           y
1               "gene_biotype "lincRNA"; gene_id "ENSG00000224818"; gene_name "RP11-134G8.8"
2 "gene_biotype "processed_transcript"; gene_id "ENSG00000261067"; gene_name "RP11-264B17.3"
3 "gene_biotype "processed_transcript"; gene_id "ENSG00000261067"; gene_name "RP11-264B17.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  extract(y, c("y"), "(ENSG\\d+)")
# x               y
# 1 1 ENSG00000224818
# 2 2 ENSG00000261067
# 3 3 ENSG00000261067
```